# save full dataframe into txt file

Tags: python, dataframe, text

I want to save the dataframe into txt file
#create the dataframe of timetable

```
import pandas as pd
timeline_table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(timeline, orient = 'index', columns = ['events'])
a = timeline_table.reset_index()
r=a.rename(columns={"index": "years"})
final_table = r.shift()[1:]
print(final_table)
```

#save the timeline/timetable into new file

```
path= "data.txt"
with open(path, mode = 'w') as output:
    output.write(f'{final_table}')
```

The output is like this:

```
1   1000  About thirty countries maintain about seventy ...
2   1270  from which derived the Old French pole antarti...
3   1391  from which derived the Old French pole antarti...
4   1773  European maps continued to show this hypotheti...
5   1775  European maps continued to show this hypotheti...
..   ...                                                ...
57  2014  In 1985, three British scientists working on d...
58  2015  With the ban of CFCs in the Montreal Protocol ...
59  2018  which operated its own scientific station—Worl...
```

I want all the rows containing sentences corresponding to the extracted years to be fully displayed in the output file.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` would be better